# Summarize my formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-equations

I would like to summarize my formula.
$p$ and $y$ are constant value, $10000$ and $0.65$.

When $n = 3$, my formula recalculate the result of $n = 2$. I don't want to recalculate. Is there way to summarize or other formula for that equivalent?

$$x_n=(p+x_{n-1})y$$

**Update :**

For More Info :

$$\begin{align}n=1 &\Rightarrow 10000 * 0.65 = 6500\\
n=2 &\Rightarrow (10000 + 6500) * 0.65 = 10725\\
n=3 &\Rightarrow (10000 + 10725) * 0.65 = 13471.25\end{align}$$

If I put $n=7$, I don't want to recalculate the result of $n=1$ to $n=6$.

Answer (score 1):

Already answered at http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/20465190/summarize-my-formula.
The general tool to deal with difference equations is Z-Transformation. The solution for the wanted initial condition $x_0=0$ is
\begin{align*}
x_n = py\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

so we have like this yes

$x_n=(10000+x_{n-1})*0.65$

so we have

$x_n=6500+0.65*x_{n-1}$

rewrite it as

$x_n-0.65*x_{n-1}=6500$

http://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/MathTutorialSF/FODF.HTM

see this please,important point is to see pattern,like  try to use recurrent relationship like this

$y_n=3*y_{n-1}$ for example  $y_{n-1}=3*y_{n-2}$  now put what is  $y_{n-1}$ from the previous,it is like this

Comment: Any way, Will I recalculate n=1 and n=2?

Comment: you will calculate only for  initial value,then use   formula directly  in this link http://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/MathTutorialSF/FODF.HTM

Comment: @CycDemo this is difference equation , you can solve it easily with the initial conditions given

Comment: See the answer to your question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465190/summarize-my-formula